# console.log reporting inconsistent values

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I have an array `angles` which contains five arrays, each of which contain two numbers.

`console.log(angles)` reports `angles[0]` to be `[1.5707963267948966, 0.7853981633974483]`. Natural conclusion is that I made a mistake in my math somewhere.

`console.log(angles[0])` reports the same values as above. However, `console.log([angles[0][0],angles[0][1]])` reports `[1, 0.5]`, which is the expected result.

Notably, `console.log(angles[0])` reports the erroneous numbers in the expanded result, but the preview displays the correct values.

[image: Screenshot]

Issue is not present for `angles[n]` where n is not 0.

What's happening here? Is there an error in `console.log`?

Comment: Is there some process that updates the values between you logging the array and expanding the details? Hover over the *i*.

Comment: Try console.log(angles.slice(0))

Comment: To add to Felix's comment, the one-line preview is generated at the time you call `console.log()`, but the expanded values are fetched when you click the arrow.

Comment: Or my favorite for this situation: `console.log(JSON.stringify(angles))` (though specifically for an array, `console.log(String(angles))` works too).

Comment: @MichaelGeary: I've never heard it put more clearly and simply than that before. Brilliant. *(Cribs for future use...)*

Comment: @FelixKling There is, I'm calling the log halfway through an AngularJS script.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thanks for the info, I didn't know that. I'll be more careful in future.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! I'll be using that in future.